# Wrap VB.net classes inside namespace

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

I have this legacy VB.net code that was written in the previous decade. This code is split across 50 different projects, which is a big maintenance nightmare. I want to consolidate all of them into a single project. I need to do this so that in the new project, there will be only one VB.net project with all of the code pulled in. There will be a top level folder for each project and would contain the code from the original project.

The problem is most of the VB.net classes dont have namespace wrapped around it. Since we combine code from multiple projects, a class Foo will be present in project 1 and project 2 with totally different functionality. My initial thought is to write a text processing utility to parse the classes and write namespace around it. Is there a better way to solve this problem than writing the tool ?

Comment: I think, you are well on the wrong way of thinking. First of all, it is not always a good idea to have all code in one solution. And second, for example, we have right now 250 projects and we have no maintenance nightmare. Squeezing all code into one project leads to less reusability and more availability when you want least availability. For example, your customer wants to build an extension on part of your code but you now need to give them all. Broken into components, you can assemble UI, services, etc, All together, this is anti-pattern. You need to pinpoint your problem, do small steps

Comment: Long story short, the dynamics of our company is different. Consolidating is the way to go for us.

Comment: I wouldn't count on your company dynamics stay same for long.